# How to use TensorBoard through two SSH connections

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line-interface, tensorboard

I use ssh to first access a server, and then ssh again once logged into that to access another server. I can't access the second server directly, it has to be through the first server. The servers are running a version of Linux.

So, how would you use TensorBoard in this scenario? Can you send the data through two SSH connections so I can open it up on Chrome on my local Windows 10 machine? If so, how could this be done?

Server 1 version: 4.15.0-120-generic
Server 2 version: 4.15.0-135-generic

Comment: <local> <ssh tunnel tfb port>  <server1> <ssh tunnel tfb port> <server2>

Comment: @404pio sorry for the basic questions, but is this executed on my local machine or the second ssh machine? And, what is ssh tunnle tfb port?

Comment: `ssh tunnle tfb port` is mental shortcut for ssh port forwarding for port used by tensorboard. Tensorboard uses 6006, so your ssh port forwarding should work on 6006 port.

Comment: `ssh tunnel` between `server1` and `server2` should be called on `server1`. But if you are familiar with ssh commands, you can run it from your local computer, e.g. ssh server1 "<command for making ssh tunnel between server1 and server2>"

Comment: Look here: https://serverfault.com/questions/699588/port-forwarding-between-3-machines